# Get index of element for Iterable

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the elegant way to find index of element in collection? For now I implemented method like this:

```
  def getIndexForValue[T] (value: T, collection: Iterable[T]): Option[Int] = {
    val pair = collection.zipWithIndex.find(_._1 == value)
    if (pair.isDefined) Some(pair.get._2) else None
  }
```

Can it be rewritten in more elegant way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
collection.indexOf(value)
```

*Note that index has no mean if collection is not subtype of Seq.*

If you really want to get `index` of any collection, you could use

```
collection.toSeq.indexOf(value)
```

Finds index of first occurrence of some value in this list after or at some start index.
elem
the element value to search for.
from
the start index
returns
the index >= from of the first element of this list that is equal (as determined by ==) to elem, or -1, if none exists.

Comment: seems `Iterable` trait doesn't have this method

Comment: What the mean of index if collection is a Set? Only Seq  have a defined order of elements.

Comment: @Eastsun, that isn't true. TreeSet has a defined iteration order, and it is a Set but not a Seq. More than a few methods on Iterable only apply to ordered collections. Paul Phillips and Martin Odersky have chimed into this discussion agreeing that the design is flawed: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/je4vZbR3WbA/_fa5aNyTyuoJ